# Does the Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat have a Sneak Peek feature?

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I am using a customised Microsoft Bot Framework [WebChat Client](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat). My bot has the capability to hand to a live chat service with an Agent, when it is unable to provide a solution to the user.

I have the requirement to allow the agents to have a "sneak peek" at what is currently being typed into the Webchat Client.

I have enabled the sendTyping feature in chat.html (i.e. sendTyping: true):

```
            BotChat.App({
            bot: bot,
            botConnection: botConnection,
            locale: 'agent',
            resize: 'window',
            sendTyping: true,    // defaults to false. set to true to send 'typing' activities to bot (and other users) when user is typing
            user: user
        }, document.getElementById('BotChatGoesHere')
        );
```

When inspecting the outbound typing message, the typing event is sent (debounced about every three seconds or so), however it contains no text. I suspect this is not a feature, however I would kindly ask the community if anyone has done this previously and if so how to implement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't supported indeed, the 'SendTyping' event doesn't contain any metadata about the state of the inputfield.

You could leverage the [backchannel](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/a62b627d4f4963576972890acf736ea9f5135e18/samples/README.md#backchannel) to send custom events. In your custom WebChat implementation, you can send a custom event on every keystroke or every x seconds. However, if you link to another agent service, maybe it can be smarter to call their / a custom API directly.

Make sure you have the consent of the user, since I don't think you can just send all keystrokes without consent.

Comment: Thanks Mick, +1 I have used a custom event and added the text metadata to the user object, which works nicely. I share your concern re: consent, we will need to address this. Appreciate your input.